# Must the customer mention the existence of my own company to the final customer?

Tags: contracts, web-development, long-term

I'm working as a freelance for 5 months.

I signed a contract between my own company and a headhunter; this contract dealing with my mission to the final customer.

So there's also a contract between this final customer and my headhunter's company.

I just learnt that the final customer ignores totally the existence of my company.
It wasn't mentioned in its contract. 
It considered me as a classical salary of my headhunter.

Basically, first contract is between my own company and the headhunter's company. 
Second contract is between the headhunter's company and the final customer's company.

Should my headhunter have declared my company to the final customer?

Comment: I don't think you are using "evoke" correctly. It certainly doesn't fit the context of the sentences and I hesitate to guess at what you may *really* mean.

Comment: evoke, meaning "mention" in this case.

Comment: I updated my OP.

Comment: I didn't really understand the quetsion.  A lot of word.  Are you asking if being outsourced is something to be declared?  My answer would be yes.

Comment: @user6035379 I m asking if final customer must know that I m not "individual" but on behalf of my own company".

Comment: sounds like a tax question to me.  sorry, I don't know.

Comment: Scott's answer below is spot on - but I'm wondering what the OP's motivation for this is in the first place!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In many cases, no.

But it all depends upon your contract with the agent/headhunter.

Unless your agreement with the headhunter specifically states they must disclose your company to all the clients you complete work for, they are perfectly fine keeping you an "invisible" entity.

In fact, this is often the backbone of some firms... they collect a stable of workers for subcontracting. Then merely become "project managers" by finding clients and delegating the work which needs to be done to their subcontractors. All the while leaving the clients the impression that the "manager" is completing all the work.

Read the contract with the "headhunter". In some instances it *specifically* prohibits you contacting their clients directly. And it's possible you are under a work-for-hire agreement with the headhunter, meaning the headhunter *owns* everything you do. Hard to say without reading the contract.

If your interest is in someone finding work specifically for you and your company, then you may be seeking an **agent** not a subcontracting agreement. Agents generally find clients, introduce you to them, then step away from the connection.

If this "headhunter" is assigning you tasks, reviewing them, then paying you... you actually **are** closer to an employee than an independent entity.